# Inconsistent font size on Mobile View depending on div height?

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

The relevant part of my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container-main">
<p>TEXT HERE<\p>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
p {
   font-size: 20px;
}
.container-mobile {
   background-color: white;
   margin-top: 100vh;
   width: 100wv;
   height: 600px;
}
```

The text is pretty small on mobile even though I set font-size to 16px. If I change height to 'auto' the font is suddenly much bigger. Why the change? And what is the preferred way to handle font size in mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Adding viewport to the header section of your page fixed the problem

```
p {
   font-size: 20px;
}
.container-mobile {
   background-color: white;
   margin-top: 100vh;
   width: 100wv;
   height: 600px;
}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<div class="container-main">
<p>TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
```